# How to call ecrecover() in pure assembly?

Tags: contract-development, evm, ecrecover, assembly

If I do remember correctly, it’s a contract built‑in in the Ethereum Virtual machine, isn’t it?

if yes, what’s the address to call for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`ecrecover`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/vm/contracts.go#L87) address is: [`0x01`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/vm/contracts.go#L45)

Without assembly you can call the [`ecrecover`](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/units-and-global-variables.html#mathematical-and-cryptographic-functions) function like that:

```
function recoverEC_Method1 (bytes32 _hash, bytes32 _r, bytes32 _s, uint8 _v) public pure returns (address) {
    bytes memory prefix = "\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32";
    bytes32 prefixedHash = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(prefix, _hash));
    return ecrecover(prefixedHash, _v, _r, _s);
}
```

With assembly (one possible alternative):

```
function recoverEC_Method2 (bytes32 _hash, bytes32 _r, bytes32 _s, uint8 _v) public view returns (address) {

    bytes memory prefix = "\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32";
    bytes32 prefixedHash = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(prefix, _hash));

    assembly {
        let pointer := mload(0x40)

        mstore(pointer, prefixedHash)
        mstore(add(pointer, 0x20), _v)
        mstore(add(pointer, 0x40), _r)
        mstore(add(pointer, 0x60), _s)

        if iszero(staticcall(not(0), 0x01, pointer, 0x80, pointer, 0x20)) {
            revert(0, 0)
        }

        let size := returndatasize
        returndatacopy(pointer, 0, size)
        return(pointer,size)
    }
}
```

Example:

```
bytes32 _hash = 0x852daa74cc3c31fe64542bb9b8764cfb91cc30f9acf9389071ffb44a9eefde46;
bytes32 _r = 0xb814eaab5953337fed2cf504a5b887cddd65a54b7429d7b191ff1331ca0726b1;
bytes32 _s = 0x264de2660d307112075c15f08ba9c25c9a0cc6f8119aff3e7efb0a942773abb0;
uint8 _v = 0x1b;
address = 0xa6fb229e9b0a4e4ef52ea6991adcfc59207c7711
```

For more information about the prefix, read the following [issue](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/3731).

> TL;DR; Geth prepends the string `\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n<length
>   of message>` to all data before signing it
>   (https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_sign). If you want
>   to verify such a signature from Solidity, you'll have to prepend the
>   same string in solidity before doing the ecrecovery.

Comment: And if there’s not enough gas for having ecrecover working with the current message, what does happens next?

Comment: A `revert` is produced. You can test it changing `not(0)` to `1000` for example.

Comment: Yes, a revert/throw is produced, but in the calling contract or inside the `ecrecover()` built‑in contract?

Comment: The `revert` is produced because of not enough gas. The `staticcall` returns `0` (fail), instead of `1`.